# nginx strips last-modified and if-modified-since headers but my rails app needs them

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, http-headers, unicorn

My Rails 3.2 app uses — via `#stale?` — `If-Modified-Since` HTTP header in the request and `Last-Modified` header in the response to decide whether it should generate some data dynamically. This works extremely well in development (whether using webrick or unicorn_rails) as `curl -D headers.txt` shows that if the correct `If-Modified-Since` value is provided a 304 response is sent, while the `Last-Modified` header is otherwise sent along the request data.

Unfortunately once deployed behind nginx, neither `If-Modified-Since` (providing the correct header value) is passed to unicorn — and thus the Rails app — nor `Last-Modified` is propagated to the client: the request is unconditionally generated and the response never contains the proper headers.

Comment: Maybe this instruction could do the trick: ignore_invalid_headers off; (i know that your headers ar not invalid...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out nginx was actually not stripping anything. Instrumentation showed that `If-Modified-Since` was received by the controller. Rails `#stale?` was receiving a request containing bad results, which resulted in a `nil` argument, swallowing it silently and subsequently ignoring comparisons to `If-Modified-Since` and positioning `Last-Modified` to `nil`.